# Can't even draw smooth empty circle in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, geometry, antialiasing

I've been searching a lot but still couldn't simply draw smooth circle in cocos2dx.

`drawCircle` haven't done their job , it draws a circle poorly.
Anyone knows the particular solution for drawing perfect smooth circle in cocos2d-x?

Here is trouble created by `drawCircle` : http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/draw-circle-with-strong-border/14827/3

Comment: Which version of cocos2d-x? On what operation system?

Comment: @WezSieTato I'm using latest cocos2d-x version 3.13.1, testing on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn on antialiasing. On iOS you can do by changing creation of CCEAGLView in AppController.mm:

```
    CCEAGLView *eaglView = [CCEAGLView viewWithFrame: [window bounds]
                                     pixelFormat: (NSString*)cocos2d::GLViewImpl::_pixelFormat
                                     depthFormat: cocos2d::GLViewImpl::_depthFormat
                              preserveBackbuffer: NO
                                      sharegroup: nil
                                   multiSampling: YES // <- by default is NO
                                 numberOfSamples: 4 ]; // <- if more samples the smoother shapes are, but more time takes the drawing
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I have, and nothing changes with this solution, please take a look on the link on my post, `drawCircle` does not draw smooth circle, it also draws broken one with `setLineWidth` > 1. http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/uploads/default/_optimized/96a/412/b86c188add_354x500.png